# htaccess - does not fall inside current context [/], ignore

Tags: .htaccess

Update

I found [this post](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/migrate-apache-rewrite-rules-to-openlitespeed/), it explains `RewriteRule` can be used in `.htaccess` but it needs to be modified.

This works, but it needs to be the second rule under `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteRule ^/?find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth/?(.*)$ https://demo.com/new-homes [L]
```

This works well for URLs like this

```
/find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth/property-type/bower
```

But how would I modify it to handle URLs with query strings?

```
/find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth-village/property-types?property_beds=&property_type_price=60000
```

---

I've made this htaccess rule

```
RewriteRule ^/?find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth/?(.*)$ https://demo.com/new-homes [R=301,L]
```

I've tested it here
https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=ebd5828d-9535-4ae9-b74a-1b70a19535a2

The htaccess.madewithlove.com validator says it works.

However, when I update `demo.com` to my actual `url` and put it on my server, it doesn't work?

I checked the server logs and I can see this error

```
2022-06-14 10:27:37.449888 [INFO] [515989] [T0] [HTAccess] [/home/wwwsite/public_html/.htaccess:7] Redirect URL [^/find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth/(.*)] does not fall inside current context [/], ignore.
```

What does `does not fall inside current context` mean and is there a way to update the `RewriteRule` so it does fall inside the current context?

I'm trying to catch multiple pages with one rule. I have a bunch of pages like this

```
https://demo.com/find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth/property-types/gilson
https://demo.com/find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth/property-types/holtham
https://demo.com/find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth/property-types/howarth
```

I'd like to catch any url that contains `find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth` and redirect to `https://demo.com/new-homes`

From what I've read, `Redirect 301` doesn't accept regex expressions - that's why I'm using a RewriteRule. Although it feels like I need to add something else to make it work.

Can anyone help?

---

`.htaccess` file. The rest of the rules work.

```
# Perch Runway
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/perch 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /perch/core/runway/start.php [L] 

# doesn't work, doesn't error?
RewriteRule ^/?find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth/?(.*)$ https://demo.com/new-homes [R=301,L]


Redirect 301 /index.htm /
Redirect 301 /portfolio.htm /find-a-home/new-homes
Redirect 301 /buyers.htm /
Redirect 301 /land.htm /
```

Comment: I'm wondering why the log message says `Redirect URL [^/find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth/(.*)]`, when your actual pattern from the rule was supposed to be `^/?find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth/?(.*)$`

Comment: I've been trying different variations, must have copied and pasted the wrong rule in the example. Neither work?

Comment: `^/find...` should never work, when you configure this in .htaccess context - the path RewriteRule matches against, has been stripped of the "prefix" leading to the current context (where the .htaccess is located) already at this point. (Can't see what exactly should be wrong with the other version though, when that leading slash is made optional.)

Comment: From this error you would seem to be on a LiteSpeed server, not Apache? "must have copied and pasted the wrong rule in the example." - this is significant, since (as CBroe mentioned), the rule you posted should "work", but the regex in the error msg would not (so the error msg is justified for _another_ rule). What is the exact error you get for the rule you've posted? Presumably `/home/wwwsite/public_html` is your document root directory?

Comment: The error was from an earlier attempt. This rule `RewriteRule ^/?find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth/?(.*)$ https://demo.com/new-homes [R=301,L]
` does not trigger an error, (I've changed the domain for this example). But it still doesn't work? Other rules work E.g. `Redirect 301 /land.htm /`

Comment: I can verify the sever is a LiteSpeed Web Server - is there a workaround?

Comment: By "doesn't work", do you mean it doesn't appear to do anything? You likely have a conflict with other directives. Please include your complete `.htaccess` file with these directives in-place. Note that modules are processed in a different order on LiteSpeed vs Apache.

Comment: Ok, I've added the `.htaccess` file to the original post

Comment: "do you mean it doesn't appear to do anything?"

Yes, no errors, nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/perch 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule .* /perch/core/runway/start.php [L] 
>
> # doesn't work, doesn't error?
> RewriteRule ^/?find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth/?(.*)$ https://demo.com/new-homes [R=301,L]
> ```

These two rules are in the wrong order. A request for `/find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth/<anything>` (which I assume does not map to a physical file) is first rewritten to `/perch/core/runway/start.php`. The second rule therefore never matches and does nothing.

Generally, external redirects need to go before internal rewrites.

These two rules can also be simplified in a couple of ways. You are not using a backreference in the *substitution* string so there is no need for the capturing subpattern (ie. `(.*)`). And the *condition* that checks that the URL does not already start `perch` should be moved to the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (the additional *condition* is not required).

For example:

```
# Redirects
RewriteRule ^find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth https://example.com/new-homes [R=301,L]

# Front-controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !perch /perch/core/runway/start.php [L]
```

The regex `^find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth` matches all URLs that *start* with that string (there is no slash prefix in `.htaccess`).

You should test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

> ```
> But how would I modify it to handle URLs with query strings?
>
> /find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth-village/property-types?property_beds=&property_type_price=60000
> ```

That depends what you mean. The above rule will already "handle URLs with query strings", in that they will be redirected. The rule above would redirect the stated URL. However, the query string is preserved by default across the redirect. If you want to remove the query string from the redirect response then include the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag on the redirect.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^find-a-home/new-homes/greenbooth https://example.com/new-homes [QSD,R=301,L]
```